# NodeJS/GraphQL: Trying to use a custom DateTime scalar and I'm getting an error

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I'm following a tutorial where the teacher is using a `String` type for his `createdAt` fields and suggested that if we wanted, to use a custom scalar type for a stronger typed `DateTime` field so I'm trying to do just that.

I'm getting the following error: `Error: Unknown type "GraphQLDateTime".`

Here is the offending code:

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server')
const { GraphQLDateTime } = require('graphql-iso-date')

module.exports = gql`
  type Post {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    body: String!
    createdAt: GraphQLDateTime!
  }
  type User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    token: String!
    username: String!
    createdAt: GraphQLDateTime!
  }
  input RegisterInput {
    username: String!
    password: String!
    confirmPassword: String!
    email: String!
  }
  type Query {
    getPosts: [Post]
    getPost(postId: ID!): Post
  }
  type Mutation {
    register(registerInput: RegisterInput): User
    login(username: String!, password: String!): User!
    createPost(body: String!): Post!
    deletePost(postId: ID!): String!
  }
`
```

I have added the `graphql-iso-date` library and VSCode's intellisense is picking that up so I know that's not the issue. It's also indicating that `GraphQLDateTime` is not being used anywhere in the file even though I'm referencing it.

I know this is probably an easy fix but I'm still new to NodeJS and GraphQL in the context of NodeJS. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Also is there another DateTime scalar that might be more preferable (Best practices are always a good idea.) Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's two steps to adding a custom scalar using `apollo-server` or `graphql-tools`:

1. Add the scalar definition to your type definitions:

   ```
   scalar DateTime
   ```
2. Add the actual GraphQLScalar to your resolver map:

   ```
   const { GraphQLDateTime } = require('graphql-iso-date')

   const resolvers = {
     /* your other resolvers */
     DateTime: GraphQLDateTime,
   }
   ```

Note that the key in the resolver map (here I used `DateTime`) has to match whatever you used as the scalar name in Step 1. This will also be the name you use in your type definitions. The name itself is arbitrary, but it needs to match.

See [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/scalars-enums/) for more details.